# sending mail from php when link in message body

Tags: php, email

i have a php script

```
<?php
$to = 'somebody@somedomain.com';
$subject = 'Test mail';
$message = 'mysitedomain.com';
$from = 'support@mysitedomain.com';
$headers = 'From:' . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo 'Mail Sent.';
?>
```

When i run this code mail not send. If i change message to mysitedomaincom (without dot before com) the mail send succesfull.

Anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Do you get an error message at all? What OS (Linux, FreeBSD, OSX Server ...) is this on? What is the email server? Are you able to confirm the email is sent by monitoring the outgoing mail log? The email that was sent, what are the headers? Lots of questions and very little info in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This codes that tells the mailer and the recipient that the email contains  well formed HTML that it will need to interpret

If you want you can change content of $message, now with this codes you can send HTML content mail.

```
<?PHP
    $to = 'somebody@somedomain.com';

    $subject = 'Test mail';

    $headers =  "From: Support <support@mysitedomain.com>" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<h1>mysitedomain.com</h1>';
    $message .= '</body></html>';

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```